# How can I run this bash command, that uses rar/winrar command line, within windows?

Tags: bash, winrar

I have this bash command that uses rar

```
for folder in */; do rar a -m0 -r "${folder%/}.rar" "$folder"; done
```

I understand from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25299584/create-a-rar-archive-for-each-subdirectory-in-a-directory-centos-ubuntu  that it creates a rar archive of each subdirectory of a directory. But that link covers ubuntu. I'm wondering how i'd run that in Windows.

I understand that Gnuwin32 is full of old versions of programs and doesn't even have rar anyway.

Cygwin is newer but doesn't include rar.exe in its list of packages.

If I try even doing $rar  in cygwin, then it says

`rar: command not found`

What can I do?

Comment: this has so many of what philosophy would call category errors that it's baffling.  You write "this winrar command"  Then you show something that is not a "winrar command" (to the extent that there even is such a thing as a winrar command).

Comment: also there is no such thing as Cgwin, it's Cygwin. And if your problem is `rar: command not found`   eg. if you run `$rar<ENTER>` then you need to look at how do you install rar in cygwin, that should be the question

Comment: And when you write "Under Gnu it tell me something about folder string."    <-- Under GNU doesn't really mean anything much.  There is a thing called GNU, which in stallman's lingo could mean an OS, or could mean some software utilities, but if software utilities then could be within any OS.  There is a thing called gnuwin32 which is old , not updated since 2010, so for over a decade, and it's for windows but you didn't really show more about what you did and what the error is

Comment: If I run `$rar` I get nothing from terminal of Cygwin

Comment: well I just looked up for the rar package in cygwin and it doesn't exist.  But you can get the rar command for windows quite easily. `C:\Program Files\WinRAR\Rar.exe`  Install winrar from https://www.rarlab.com/download.htm     which mentions https://www.rarlab.com/rar/winrar-x64-602.exe  Then you have to kno how to add a directory to a path e.g. `PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\WinRAR`  so you can run rar.exe from any directory And if you look `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\WinRAR` it'll have a manual for how to use the command line `rar.exe`

Comment: so forget gnuwin32  for this 'cos everything with gnuwin32 is old and rarlab have the latest. . And forget cygwin too. 'cos you can probably use cmd.exe for this though it could be possible to use rar.exe from rarlab, with cygwin. But simpler to just use cmd.exe and the rar.exe from rarlab. And not bash, just cmd.

Comment: I guess you are trying to do https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25299584/create-a-rar-archive-for-each-subdirectory-in-a-directory-centos-ubuntu  "Create a RAR archive for each subdirectory in a directory "  as that mentions the command you mention of `for folder in */; do rar a -m0 -r "${folder%/}.rar" "$folder"; done`   So that uses bash. You could try that in cygwin letting cygwin use rar.exe from rarlab,  though I haven't tried it! And do it first with the echo like the example in the question!

Comment: see https://pastebin.com/raw/5R0aBbRC   you can get rarlab rar.exe to run in cygwin and you could use that bash line.  I've edited that stackoverflow question that has your command and included the output of it so you can see if it's what you want

Comment: @barlop I will try to follow your directions to use only cmd. Yes, but if I use CMD only is there a workaround to use that bash command under CMD? However to ask this question. I tried this tutorial before, but it didn't work for me.
https://jwgoerlich.com/tip-cygwin-for-rar-archives/ - I also installed make package when I installed cygwin but I get an error about make file or something and also for mv unrar.exe /bin.

Comment: cygwin is fine and you can use  that bash command in cygwin and you can use rar.exe in cygwin

Comment: Do you even know what that bash command you have in your question does?  Are you aware that that command is to "Create a RAR archive for each subdirectory in a directory" as in that SO link where you maybe got the command.  The link you just gave though doesn't even use the rar command.

Comment: And it may well be that your question doesn't bear much resemblance to what you are trying to do. Besides that your whole approach is completely wrong by any standard/measure/philosophy. And it's not clear where you got your "command" from that you are trying to fix.

Comment: Yes, I know what that bash command do. If I have some folders like `one`, `two`, `three` inside a parent directory then that command make `one.rar`, `two.rar`, `three.rar`

Comment: @barlop - it works ! thank you for pastebin fix ! Look here https://imgur.com/2fpDLFK.png

Comment: ,,,,,,,,,,,,,great

Comment: shall I rewrite your question(not changing what you're meaning to  ask), but making it better quality, and then post an answer, and then you can accept the answer?

Comment: @barlop yes, sure I will accept your answer if you write it

Comment: done i've improved the quality of your question and posted an answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128175/discussion-between-barlop-and-user3520363).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two ways you could do this.. one way is to run rar.exe from cmd.exe without cygwin. But then you'd need to adjust your command to run with batch rather than bash.

The other way is to run rar.exe from cygwin. Then you can use your bash command directly. We'll try that route

You can run external executables from within cygwin.

you can get the rar command for windows quite easily and it ends up in `C:\Program Files\WinRAR\Rar.exe`

Install winrar from rarlab.com/download.htm which mentions rarlab.com/rar/winrar-x64-602.exe

Then you have to know how to add a directory to a shell's path variable, so you can run rar.exe from any directory (and in your case since using cygwin, that'd be the bash way of adding a directory to the path variable)

And if you look `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\WinRAR` it'll have a manual for how to use the command line rar.exe

```
$ /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/WinRAR/Rar.exe | head -n 7

RAR 6.02 x64   Copyright (c) 1993-2021 Alexander Roshal   11 Jun 2021
Trial version             Type 'rar -?' for help

Usage:     rar <command> -<switch 1> -<switch N> <archive> <files...>
               <@listfiles...> <path_to_extract\>



user@hp-probook1 ~
$ PATH=$PATH:/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/WinRAR

user@hp-probook1 ~
$ /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/WinRAR/Rar.exe | head -n 7

RAR 6.02 x64   Copyright (c) 1993-2021 Alexander Roshal   11 Jun 2021
Trial version             Type 'rar -?' for help

Usage:     rar <command> -<switch 1> -<switch N> <archive> <files...>
               <@listfiles...> <path_to_extract\>


user@hp-probook1 ~
$ rar | head -n 7

RAR 6.02 x64   Copyright (c) 1993-2021 Alexander Roshal   11 Jun 2021
Trial version             Type 'rar -?' for help

Usage:     rar <command> -<switch 1> -<switch N> <archive> <files...>
               <@listfiles...> <path_to_extract\>


user@hp-probook1 ~
$
```

So you see now you have rar running.

And now your command will run just as good as it does here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25299584/create-a-rar-archive-for-each-subdirectory-in-a-directory-centos-ubuntu

```
user@hppro ~
$ ls -l
total 3
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 user None  0 Aug  2 03:17 abcd_dir
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 user None  0 Aug  2 03:18 defgh_dir
-rwx------  1 user None 86 Dec 24  2020 blahfile

user@hppro ~
$ for folder in */; do echo rar a -m0 -r "${folder%/}.rar" "$folder"; done
rar a -m0 -r abcd_dir.rar abcd_dir/
rar a -m0 -r defgh_dir.rar defgh_dir/

user@hppro ~
$
```

And as the user showed, having removed the echo. And set up cygwin bash's path, and installed winrar including the command line rar.exe and  then running the command.

[image]